# Intermittent (no route) to a newly requisitioned softlayer virtual server

Tags: routes, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are implementing a tool that allows virtual machines to be added to a hadoop cluster on demand. The idea is to requisition some servers on demand, have them participate in the hadoop cluster and return them when not needed.

The problem is that intermittently, there seems to be no  path to the newly requisitioned virtual node.   For example:

- I "slcli vs create" a new node
- Wait till READY.
- copy over the tools to this newly acquired server.
- Sometimes, ssh root@123.456.789.0  will timeout.  Other times, I can log on without any issues.  Ball park figures are something like every 3 - 4th ode allocated will not be able to resolve the private ip address.
- The route seems to resolve itself after several hours.  But this "at some point" is not conducive to reasonable tool execution. I can only say "seems" because I have not witnessed routes resolving 100% of the time.

To me, this is a bug.  When you report READY (slcli vs ready "newNode" --timeout=600) I should be able to log on 100% of the time.

If not, how can I know whether the newNode is ready?

Thanks.

Comment: After the VM was completely provisioned, did you perform any other action like os reload, configure firewall, upgrade the VM, add additional subnet, etc?. If yes, in some cases the VSI requires restart in order to complete active transactions.

Comment: You can also check the status by using the command "slcli vs detail <vsi_id>". Look for the status, state, active_transaction

Comment: No OS reload.   Just requisitioned the VS, loaded with Centos.  So, hardly anytime to do something crazy like reload os.    No firewalls installed.     I don't believe polling on the details as you suggest will bare any fruits because, once I execute the "create" (asynchronous), I perform "slcli vs ready" which will block  until the host(s) are ready.  private and public ip's are set, and the status and state will be Active and Running.  And that would be correct... except I don't have access until some blessed process in the background somewhere bores a hole through.

Comment: Since the VSI is Active, Running, and there isn't Pending Active Transactions, I recommend you submit a ticket to Softlayer, they can check what is happening with your VSI, don't forget provide the VSI ID.

Comment: lol.  Thank you Albert.  We have a feed back loop now.   support team asked me to come to stack overflow to get the answers from the developers.

Comment: FYI, see ticket:  41937279

Answer (score 0):

The command "slcli vs ready" looks for **activeTransactions** and **provisionDate** to provide the respective answer, you can see the code here https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/managers/vs.py, code line 393.

The VSI should be ready (completely provisioned) after 10-20 min for Linux OS , about 1h to 1h 30min in the worst case. For Windows OS is about 40min to 1 hr.

**How long should we wait after the READY response is received?**

There are many internal transactions, and in some cases, these take more time to be solved. Next are some possible cases:

> - Datacenter you selected is overcrowded because there are many request on that time
> - Selected VLAN is getting problems while is being attached to VSI
> - Selected image template has issues.
> - Internal transactions are taking long time to be solved because the VSI is far away (Network problems during transport). On this case, I
>     suggest you to select datacenters near to your country.
> - .....

I can only help you with API problems from client side. Since you are getting the correct answer from SLCLI (ready / not ready), I can't help you with your problem about the intermittent connection.

If you feels that your VSI is taking long time to be ready, you can ask to the Virtualization department in your ticket or create a new one.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Hi Albert, thank you very much for taking the time to address this issue.  It seems like the initial assumption on the virtual server allocation is really not geared towards automation.    At this point, after the node is READY, there are no formal means for me to determine if the node is usable.  Of course, we can go through the front door (public) and it looks like that 's the only option.   And I guess  programmatically I can try to ping until it works or times out.  Not very quenching is it?